# How to combine Pandas dataframe according to unique column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files. One is called 'master_registry.csv' and another one is 'master_reference.csv'.  Both of these CSV files have a column called 'Master_Id'. I have filtered some values including 'Master_Id' from the 'master_registery.csv' and created new data frame called 'df' and also I have filtered some values including 'Master_Id' from 'master_reference.csv' and created a new data frame called 'df2'. So both of these data frames have 'Master_Id' column. Now I want to create new data frame by combining both 'df' and 'df2' data frames. Can anyone help me do this?

```
    # reading CSV from the directory
    master_registry = pd.read_csv('application/master_registry.csv')
    master_reference = pd.read_csv('application/master_registry.csv')

    # filtering some selected columns form the csv
    df = master_registry .filter(items=['Master_ID', 'Provider First Name', 'Provider Last Name (Legal Name)', 'Provider Credential Text', 'Provider Gender Code','Provider License Number State Code_1',
                    'Provider Business Practice Location Address City Name'])

    df2 = master_reference .filter(items=['Master_ID', 'Client_Reference_ID'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [join method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). Usage below -

```
df.set_index('Master_ID').join(df2.set_index('Master_ID'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to merge the two data frames by 'Master ID'. You can have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297589/merge-two-data-frames-based-on-common-column-values-in-pandas).

I think this should solve your problem: `pd.merge(df, df2, on='Master_ID')`

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  Quote the relevant part of the link because links can go invalid over time.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have edited the answer and have tried to make it useful. Thanks!