# Merge/Join in pandas based on date in range of min/max dates in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I follow this thread which doesn't fully answer my solution : [Best way to join / merge by range in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas)

I precise that my min/max in my case are DateTime but this works without any problem.

The accepted answer works fine for me, however I think this could be optimized for my use case.

Indeed, it will create a mega datframe which concatenates both A and B df, whereas I would need only the rows where A_id and B_id match exactly.

My original df has 79k rows. After processing this

```
C = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([A.values[i], B.values[j]]),
    columns=A.columns.append(B.columns)
)
```

I have a df of 2.3 m rows, which when I keep only `C[C['A_id'] == C['B_id']]` goes back to 74k rows which is what I expect.

How can I do it directly in the first operation, improving at the same time the time to process ?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout [Merge two data frames based on common column values in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297589/merge-two-data-frames-based-on-common-column-values-in-pandas) @yeye

Comment: Yes but the thing is that with the need of comparing the min/max value between the 2 df, the best solution in terms of performance seems to be using this method. I just need to tweak it so that it only retrieves me the matching rows only, instead of all.
If I do if after I think this is not the most optimized way of doing it

Comment: Merge two dataframe using `left_on='A_id'` and `right_on='B_id'` and then check for min/max of datetime .

Comment: Doing like this is too long to process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way.

I added Series, and added the condition in the `i, j = np.where((a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] <= bh))` of the related topic

Now I have:

```
a = A.A_value.values
aId = A.A_id.values
bId = B.B_id.values
bh = B.B_high.values
bl = B.B_low.values

i, j = np.where((a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] <= bh) & (aId[:, None] == bId)
```

This is almost instantaneous for my 80k lines whereas before it took 3 seconds