# Pandas matching rows by dates between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes.

dfA has 848 rows

dfB has 600 rows

Both have Date column as Index.

I want to find the 600 rows in dfA that match the dates in dfB -- dfA should end with 600 rows that match dfB.

Trying something like below but isn't working...

```
dfA.iloc(dfB.index)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do, and share example input/output and a [mcve]. In any case, this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297589/merge-two-data-frames-based-on-common-column-values-in-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
dfA.reindex(index = dfB.index)
```

or [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
dfA.loc[dfB.index]
```

or if that column is not really set as an `index` you can do:

```
dfA.set_index('Date').reindex(index = dfB['Date'])
```