# How to convert multiple columns in pandas DataFrame into one columns using label encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a Movie Recommender using Machine Learning with python.
The csv data is of form:

> Movie ID,Movie Name,IMDB 
>   Rating,**Biography,Drama,Thriller,Comedy,Crime,Mystery,History**,Label
>   58,The Imitation Game,8,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
>   8,Ex Machina,7.7,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0

```
Movie_recommendation_data = pd.read_csv('movies.csv', index_col = 'Movie Name')
X = movie_recommendation_data[['Biography','Drama','Thriller','Comedy','Crime','Mystery','History']]
y = movie_recommendation_data['Movie ID']
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
```

How can I convert the bold columns into one column where I can use Label Encoding to easily determine the genres. Any Suggestions?

Comment: There is already a solution for this problem. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297589/merge-two-data-frames-based-on-common-column-values-in-pandas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGED_COLUMN = pd.concat([pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.Biography),
 pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.Drama),
 pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.Thriller), 
 pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.Comedy),
 pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.Crime),
 pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.Mystery),
 pd.Series(Movie_recommendation_data.History)], ignore_index = True)
```

This will result in a single column which contains all the columns merged into one.

> To add corresponding Labels to each Genre. First count the number of Genres. In your case its 7. Then just iterate each Label 7 times in a new column.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is helpful. But can you please help me to use label encoding along with so that I won't loose data?

Comment: You want the Labels in the corresponding column as well?
Like this?
Label | Rating;
58 | 1;
58 | 0;